# Add an individual column to cxGrid and use for selection purposes (checkbox)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, tcxgrid

I do not want to add a database field in my actual database to use for selection purpose so I thought to use cxGrid's ability to add a separate field in the grid. I add the field,name it (select),change it's property to that of 'checkbox' but it seems I cant use it as it is not selectable in the grid. It behaves like read-only. How can I enable such thing ? Also,how do you later manipulate with such selected record in the grid ? (example: I want to insert that selected record under another date).

[image: unable to select]

Comment: Which dataset are you using. Some datasets can use temporary field. This field is not related with the database.

Comment: If you're asking whether you can have a read/write checkbox column that's not bound to a data column, it certainly used to be (in the days of version 3 of Devex's Quantum Grid) and somewhere or other I found their documentation on how to do it.  Unfortunately, i haven't managed to find it just now.  ISTR that it was a question of adding (in code) an unbound TdxTreeList check column to the grid (reason I remember was that I was surprised the QG allowed an unbound column to a data-bound grid) and then handling the OnMouseUp event to toggle the state of the check box. Was 10 years ago, though ...

Comment: Btw, I also STR that the point of using an unbound column was that it allowed the checkbox's state to be independent of the data in the dataset.  Similar to what @Ravault123 mentioned, I guess, but implemented differently.

Comment: using sqlite with Unidac.

Comment: Add new field as fkInternalCalc into the DataSet of unidac (TFDTable). Also set the Tcxgrid.TcxGridDBTableView.DataController.DataModeController.GridMode to True.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things you need to do.
1. Set the new field's ValueType property.
2. Set the DataController.KeyFieldName property.

See https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A1095 for step-by-step instructions from DevExpress.

Answer (score -1):

Click `checkbox column`->`databinding`->`valuetype`,

Change the `valuetype` to `boolean`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Change the valuetype to boolean

Comment: Add this comment to the answer because one liner answer are expected to delete soon and also explain how it will be useful to other future readers.